# How can I send a multi part mime email from my mac

Tags: email

How can I send a multi part mime email from my mac for the purposes of sending a html email together with a plain text version. The emails I send will be going out to a single recipient each time.

Comment: Can you clarify how you would send the mail if it weren't multi-part mime (ie, would you send it via a shell script, php, etc) ?

Comment: @Kent, I would use Apple Mail

Answer (score 1):

Mail.app sends a multipart mime email with hrml and plain text alternatives if you select Format->make Rich text

Comment: No, it's rich text not HTML

Comment: No it is HTML - send a mail to yourself and then look at the raw source. The original NeXT Mail.app used HTML but OSX changed it to HTML but left the menu option as is

Comment: OK, let's clarify. Mail.app sends HTML but a user cannot edit an HTML email. You cannot include links, you cannot use HTML tags. You have some very limited formatting options that are then sent as HTML.

Comment: You can add a link when writing a mail message.  Highlight the word(s) you want linked, control-click (right-click), and follow the "Link->" context menu.  Add the URL.